# Managing querystrings with urlreferrer in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url, query-string, response.redirect

**VB.NET**

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath & "?query=1")
```

*This is a working example of how to navigate to the urlreferrer and include a new querystring.*

**THE PROBLEM**

When urlreferrer includes an existing querystring the rendered markup becomes:

```
url.aspx?existing=1?query=1
```

The url does not resolve correctly because of the second **?** which should instead be **&**

**QUESTION**

How to determine if a urlreferrer already has querystring and implement the correct code to accomodate?

**SOLUTION**

```
    If (Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString.Contains("?")) Then
      Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString & "&query=1")
    Else
      Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString & "?query=1")
    End If
```

***AbsoluteUrl does not include querystrings use OrigionalString as referrer.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little logic:

```
If Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString.Contains("?") Then
   ...
Else
   ...
End If
```

Comment: I did consider this obvious approach however am wary that a URL may contain a ? not derived from a querystring. What's your thoughts?

Comment: can you hang your hat on `.aspx?` instead?  The `?` character is a reserved character and the only place it would be is in a querystring parameter as data or as the separator of params, either way it indicates parameters and will work 100%

Comment: Even in encryted strings? Either way aspx? will work 100% thanks man.

Comment: well you wouldn't encode/encrypt the URI, you would do that to the querystring parameters.

Comment: Fixed the issue but had to use OriginalString instead of Absolute Url to keep querystrings intact.

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help. Up vote for me then?  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is a ? in de Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath:

```
If (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.Contains("?")) Then
   Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath & "&query=1")
Else
   Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath & "?query=1")
End If
```